# WinUI 3 freeform user control

Tags: user-controls, winui-3

Is it possible to create a user control with a freeform border so that its children are clipped to the border? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I suggest you could try to create a user control and then use [Opacity Masks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/opacity-masks-overview) to realize freeform border.